# Accessing current_user in AMS 0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I instantiate AMS in view context that way

```
s = BusinessSerialize.new(object, scope: self)
ActiveModel::Serializer.adapter.new(s)
```

How should i access current_user in `ActiveModel::Serializers` v0.10.0? I keep getting `` undefined local variable or method `current_user' ``

The only way to get it - `scope.current_user`

Answer (score 0):

One way to access it is to set the `serialization_scope` as, for example, `view_context`. You can do this in your `application_controller` and then customize it in the other controllers, if your needs change.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  serialization_scope :view_context
end
```

And then in serializer:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :body, :can_edit

  def can_edit
    true if scope.current_user.can_edit?(object)
  end

end
```

Here's some documentation that will certainly help better than me:

- https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#customizing-scope
- https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/624

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done easily in few steps by implementing Thread.

Step 1:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end

  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end

end
```

Step 2:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
end
```

Now you can easily get current user as User.current in models and serializers